# PHP reorder array based upon key

Tags: php, arrays

Consider the following array `$arr_sessions`:

```
[
  {
    "url": "2019_7_5_0_52_RACE.json",
    "trackName": "road-america"
  },
  {
    "url": "2019_7_5_0_27_RACE.json",
    "trackName": "road-america"
  },
  {
    "url": "2019_7_5_0_16_QUALIFY.json",
    "trackName": "road-america"
  },
  {
    "url": "2019_7_5_0_0_PRACTICE.json",
    "trackName": "road-america"
  },
  {
    "url": "2019_7_4_23_9_RACE.json",
    "trackName": "ttassen"
  },
  {
    "url": "2019_7_4_23_52_RACE.json",
    "trackName": "ttassen"
  },
  {
    "url": "2019_7_2_11_25_RACE.json",
    "trackName": "road-america"
  },
  {
    "url": "2019_7_2_11_03_RACE.json",
    "trackName": "road-america"
  }
]
```

Based upon this array I'd like to create a new `$arr_results` as follows:

```
[
  {
    "url": [
      "2019_7_5_0_52_RACE.json",
      "2019_7_5_0_27_RACE.json",
      "2019_7_5_0_16_QUALIFY.json",
      "2019_7_5_0_0_PRACTICE.json"
    ],
    "trackName": "road-america"
  },
  {
    "url": [
      "2019_7_4_23_9_RACE.json",
      "2019_7_4_23_52_RACE.json"
    ],
    "trackName": "ttassen"
  },
  {
    "url": [
      "2019_7_2_11_25_RACE.json",
      "2019_7_2_11_03_RACE.json"
    ],
    "trackName": "road-america"
  }
]
```

As you can see, the requirements here are to combine the values for 'url' for as long as 'trackName' **stays the same as the next one**, however don't group them if the same 'trackName' should exist somewhere else (like in this example we have 2 times "road-america", however these shouldn't get combined since there is a different 'trackName' in between).

So far I spend significant time trying to figure it out how to get there (I guess this has to be done with nested loops?)

### Update

Here's 1 of the things I tried (but clearly this only looks at the next 'trackName' - not sure how to continue from here)

```
for ($s = 0; $s < count($arr_sessions); $s++) {

    $n= $s+1;

    if($arr_sessions[$n]["trackName"] == $arr_sessions[$s]["trackName"]){
        $arr_results[$s]['name'] = $arr_sessions[$s]["sessionName"];
        $arr_results[$s]['log'] = array($arr_sessions[$s]["url"], $arr_sessions[$n]["url"]);
        $s += 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try looping the array?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I did but I failed to understand how to do it correctly. Thanks

Comment: Show what you tried, then we'll show you how to fix it. We're not going to write it for you from scratch.

Comment: It should just be a matter of setting a variable to the last `trackName`. Then you check if `$current['trackName'] == $prev_trackname`. If it is, you add to the current element of the result, otherwise you start a new element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't look at the next trackname, save the trackname from the previous iteration in a variable. Whenever it changes, you start a new element in the results array.

```
$arr_results = [];
$prev_trackname = null;
$i = -1;
foreach ($arr_sessions as $current) {
    if ($current['trackName'] != $prev_trackname) {
        $i++;
        $arr_results[$i] = ['trackName' => $current['trackName'], 'url' => []];
        $prev_trackname = $current['trackName'];
    }
    $arr_results[$i]['url'][] = $current['url'];
}
```

Comment: you're awesome!! Thanks a lot! (now let me study what you did here). Thanks again!

Comment: I wondered, this is not gonna work because it's gonna renew `url` property each time in line `8`.

Comment: Assigning to `$arr_results[$i]['url'][]` means to push onto the array, not replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example with output. You need to check if the track name is the same as the previous one, and build your array accordingly.

```
$a = json_decode('[
  {
    "url": "2019_7_5_0_52_RACE.json",
    "trackName": "road-america"
  },
  {
    "url": "2019_7_5_0_27_RACE.json",
    "trackName": "road-america"
  },
  {
    "url": "2019_7_5_0_16_QUALIFY.json",
    "trackName": "road-america"
  },
  {
    "url": "2019_7_5_0_0_PRACTICE.json",
    "trackName": "road-america"
  },
  {
    "url": "2019_7_4_23_9_RACE.json",
    "trackName": "ttassen"
  },
  {
    "url": "2019_7_4_23_52_RACE.json",
    "trackName": "ttassen"
  },
  {
    "url": "2019_7_2_11_25_RACE.json",
    "trackName": "road-america"
  },
  {
    "url": "2019_7_2_11_03_RACE.json",
    "trackName": "road-america"
  }
]');

// Set previous track to null
$prev_track = NULL;
// New array
$new_a = [];
// Set counter
$i = 0;

foreach ($a as $value) {

  // If previous track name is different than current track name
  if ($prev_track !== $value->trackName) {

    // Increment counter
    $i++;
    // Create a new array entry
    $new_a[$i] = ['trackName' => $value->trackName, 'url' => [$value->url]];

  } else {
    // Append to previously created array entry
    $new_a[$i]['url'][] = $value->url;
  }

  // Set previous track to current track
  $prev_track = $value->trackName;
}

print json_encode(array_values($new_a));
```

This will output:

```
[
  {
    "trackName": "road-america",
    "url": [
      "2019_7_5_0_52_RACE.json",
      "2019_7_5_0_27_RACE.json",
      "2019_7_5_0_16_QUALIFY.json",
      "2019_7_5_0_0_PRACTICE.json"
    ]
  },
  {
    "trackName": "ttassen",
    "url": [
      "2019_7_4_23_9_RACE.json",
      "2019_7_4_23_52_RACE.json"
    ]
  },
  {
    "trackName": "road-america",
    "url": [
      "2019_7_2_11_25_RACE.json",
      "2019_7_2_11_03_RACE.json"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $arr_sessions is actually JSON you can try following code:

```
$output = [];
$data = json_decode($input);

foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
    if(isset($output[$value->trackName])) {
        array_push($output[$value->trackName]['url'], $value->url);
    } else {
        $output[$value->trackName] = [
            'trackName' => $value->trackName,
            'url' => [$value->url]
        ];
    }
}
$your_desired_format = array_values($output);
```

Comment: a valid point, however my array is already decoded from an existing JSON, and I'm writing a new JSON file based upon this new array. Thanks!

Comment: Won't this group all with the same track name? That is not what OP requested

Comment: @Andreas no, if trackName exist in associative array just url will be added, otherwise new key (trackName) will be created.

Comment: No, see https://3v4l.org/jZmSc you mix all track names in one subarray see OPs request. There should be three subarrays not two

Comment: @Andreas I see, I grouped it generally and OP wanted group for every track Name which are in a row. Anyway that variant can be useful as well). Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```php
$lastKey = '';
$index = 0;
$arr = [];
foreach ($arr_sessions as $record) {
  $trackName = $record->trackName;
  if ($lastKey !== $trackName) {
    $lastKey = $trackName;
    $index++;
  }
  if (!$arr[$index]) {
    $arr[$index] = (object) [
      'trackName' => $lastKey,
      'url' => []
    ];  
  }
  array_push($arr[$index]->url, $record->url);
}
$arr = array_values($arr);
print_r($arr);
```